# Обособление оборота причины

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп, присоединительная-конструкция

Как правильно? (Этот оборот, из-за которого я ставлю двоеточие, обозначает-таки, если что, причину.) Думаю, 2-й вариант – это тот самый, правильный.

1. Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город, и не знаю, когда смогу.
2. Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город – и не знаю, когда смогу.
3. Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город, – и не знаю, когда смогу.
4. Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город; и не знаю, когда смогу.

Comment: Да, вы правы, второй.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основное высказывание: *Я не смогу встретиться и не знаю, когда смогу.*
Союз ***и*** может быть присоединительным, тогда напишем с запятой или с точкой:
*Я не смогу встретиться, и не знаю, когда смогу.*
*Я не смогу встретиться. И не знаю, когда смогу.*

В эту структуру вклинивается ***поехал за город*** – причина, относящаяся к первой части.

*Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город, и не знаю, когда смогу.*

Этот вариант, на мой взгляд, плохо смотрится и плохо читается. Двоеточие – сильный знак, и здесь получается так, как будто последняя часть тоже относится к нему. Запятой недостаточно. Чтобы выразить нужный смысл и показать его интонационно и графически, нужен ещё один сильный знак.

Поэтому выбирайте из трёх вариантов (правила позволяют):

*Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город – и не знаю, когда смогу.

Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город, – и не знаю, когда смогу.

Я не смогу встретиться: поехал за город. И не знаю, когда смогу.*

Comment: *и здесь получается так, как будто последняя часть тоже относится к нему* — вот, мне тоже так показалось.

Comment: Чего вы слились с разговора о "всё-таки"? Потом удалим.

Comment: @oleedd Спасибо за поддержку! // Там я уже не вижу смысла обсуждать. Для меня нормально звучит. И смысл никуда не уходит, если видеть в контексте. *"Когда он всё же пришёл?"* – то же самое.

Comment: Проблема вот в чём. "Всё-таки" буквально имеет смысл "вопреки ожидаемому" (по словарям). *Он, вопреки ожидаемому, пришёл(?)* Здесь этот смысл к месту. *Когда он, вопреки ожидаемому, пришёл?* А здесь нет. Ну не говорят так. Просто хотят узнать когда, а не когда, вопреки чему-то. Поэтому мне режет слух. Но это довольно тонкая вещь, которую сложно уловить. Поэтому мне сложно доказать. Поэтому не хочется бросать.

Comment: Ну, может, просто не все тонкости разговорной речи, не все значения включены в словари.

Comment: Да, вот есть вводное значение "всё-таки интересно"/"всё-таки опять спрошу" (обычно в начале предложения: *И всё-таки...*), при нём тоже не обособляют, но его нет в словарях (может, чтобы не было непоняток, почему вводное не обособляется), хотя пример с ним есть. Если такое значение, то корректно, но говорю за "вопреки ожидаемому".

Comment: "Слова «а всё ж(е)», «а всё ж таки», «а всё-таки», стоящие в начале предложения, могут отделяться запятой при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_115). А у нас разговорная речь, переставили в середину, убрали "а", не обособили.

Comment: Интересно, не знал, что у них такое есть. Но в вопросах это уже другое значение (никак не "вопреки..."). Но может быть и в середине с ним. Как всегда, более сложному меньше внимания уделено. Не-не, у "-таки" нет такого значения, просто заменил его на "всё-таки" (полная версия), чтобы был лучше понятен смысл. Оно же к словам примыкает, самостоятельного значения нет. В Леопольдовском оригинале: *Когда он к нам придёт-таки?* => *Когда он к нам придёт, вопреки ожидаемому?* Мне режет слух.

Comment: У него много чего режет :))

Comment: Но все пошли против меня :(

Comment: Так нет, я же только на ваши предложения среагировал. О том, что для меня они норм.

Comment: Думаю, для вас норм, если значение — "всё-таки хочу узнать", а не "вопреки ожидаемому", что соответствует "-таки".

Comment: Да.............

Comment: Ну вот, хоть кому-то удалось доказать, а то эта ситуация меня огорчила, даже разочаровала.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ **изменен.**

1. Есть **еще один вариант**:

*Я не смогу встретиться **– поехал за город,** – и не знаю, когда смогу.*

Здесь обособление двумя тире (по правилам для вставных конструкций). По семантике и произношению вариант подходит. **Причина** указана как добавочное пояснение.

В этом случае обозначена основная структура предложения:

*Я не смогу встретиться, и (я) не знаю, когда смогу.*

В результате мы имеем **более сильный знак** (запятая и тире),  чем просто тире для сложной конструкции.

2. **Сравним** с вариантом из заданного вопроса.

*Я не смогу встретиться: **поехал за город,** – и не знаю, когда смогу.*

Здесь разные **пары знаков**: два тире или двоеточие и тире.

Двоеточие требует остановки голоса, при этом причина **подчеркивается**. Интонация предупредительная/пояснительная, делается увеличенная пауза.

При выборе тире (не двоеточия) интонация **предупредительная**, пауза меньше.

Поэтому здесь автор может **выбрать**: подчеркивать или нет.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148832/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: А сразу изменить — нет, надо только нервы трепать!

Comment: Тоже пришли мои ошибки считать? Сколько  раз мне разрешите менять ответы? Можно не два, а хотя  бы три раза, а?   Никак до людей не доходит, что я не меняю ответы, не списываю их у вас, а думаю. И СВОЕ решение могу изменить, если он МНЕ перестало нравиться.

Comment: Надо сразу реагировать на замечания, а не опосля :)

Comment: Надо отвечать правильно, тогда не придётся ничего менять :)

Comment: Sharon, я тоже думал о замене двоеточия. Мне этот вариант нравится.

Comment: С двоеточием чёткое указание на причину. А с тире общая дополнительная информация (плохо подходит).

Comment: @oleedd Даже причину допустимо обозначать тире ("параллельное использование знаков").

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Не, тогда нет прямого указания причины, тогда просто подчёркивание. Как-то Sharon на это намекала, даже Лопатин. Как бы причина, но мы присоединяем, потому что нет чёткой причинной формулировки.

Comment: @oleedd Ну не знаю... Из Розенталя об этом:  *А углубляться мы не могли — земля промёрзла; С таким напарником можно хоть на Марс лететь (: —) надёжный товарищ*.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну вот здесь автору захотелось подчеркнуть факт, что земля промёрзла, больше, чем делать указание на причину. Смотрим, что нам нужнее — подчёркивание или указание на причину.

Comment: Ну и ладно.....

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ну а то, что причина, понимаем по смыслу. Вот и получается параллельное использование знаков. Но ключевое — что при тире подчёркивание (что не всегда уместно).

Comment: Со вставкой получается, что информация второстепенная, а по смыслу она первостепенная (причина всё-таки важна).

Comment: @oleedd  Честно, вот всё равно, потому что терминология абстрактная: у Sharon двоеточие подчёркивает, у вас – тире. И вставка (синтаксически второстепенная) часто несёт самую суть. Для меня тире – более эффектный знак, в силу того что оно занимает много места, а двоеточие прилепится к соседней букве, что вообще можно не заменить. :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Та не, не надо графической пунктуации. Лучше шрифты интересные подбирайте. *И вставка (синтаксически второстепенная) часто несёт самую суть* — значит, неправильно, это в корне неверно. Да мы постоянно тире что-нибудь подчёркиваем. Про двоеточие такого не слышал.

Comment: @oleedd Не понял, что в корне неверно?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Делать вставку из того, что несёт самую суть. С таким графическим подходом вообще про двоеточие забудут(

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец У вас прямо дискриминация знака из-за его размера. Надо очки одевать, чтобы не слипалось :)

Comment: @oleedd Не забудут, у него хорошие функции. Да я немножко шучу, вижу всё, и очки надеваю. А данное предложение можно прочитать с разной интонацией, а можно с одинаковой, что с тем, что с другим знаком. Но суть останется, мы в любом случае получим сообщение о причине "несмогения".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Первостепенность информации не надо игнорировать. Во вставке вспомогательные вещи. И подчёркивать здесь нечего, в отличие от примера Розенталя.

Comment: @oleedd  Да кто ж её игнорирует, если она подчёркнута тире? Да ещё с двух сторон. Всё, больше не могу и не хочу.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вставочные тире просто вставочные, они не подчёркивают. Кстати, как вы относитесь к современному варианту "одеваю" вместо "надеваю"?

Comment: @oleedd  А что, этот вариант уже нормирован? Сейчас я легко к таким вещам отношусь, потому что понимаю, что с этим трудно, и наверно невозможно, бороться.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Нет, конечно. Но только такой и слышу. Поэтому мне он ближе.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Даже Джим это одобрил, и сказал, что лингвисты навязывают свои правила (которые им взбрели в голову).